# Where are the details for the Faerie Form spell?

Tags: spells, adnd-2e

On page 803 in the *Priest's Spell Compendium Volume 3* listed under Elven deity Erevan Ilesere there's a spell called *Faerie Form* which is supposed to be 7th level.

When I went to the "F" section in the book, which begins on page 257 in the *Priest's Spell Compendium Volume 1*, the spell wasn't there. The section begins with *Faerie Fire* then *Faerie Flames - Elf* but moves into *Faith Armor* instead of *Faerie Form*. The spell is not listed in the index on page 818 in the *Priest's Spell Compendium Volume 3* either.

*Sylvan Form* exists in the compendium but it is a 4th level spell as to where *Faerie Form* is clearly a 7th level spell. *Monster Mythology* where the Elven deities are described doesn't seem to contain the spell either.

So, where are the details for this spell? Which book is it located in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The spell ***faerie form*** appears in [*Demihuman Deities*](http://www.rpgnow.com/product/17534/Demihuman-Deities-2e?it=1) on page 111. It has a casting time of 1 round, a duration of 1 hour/level, and is like the spell *shapechange* except that only faerie forms can be assumed.

Comment: Notably, in the *DD* spell index it’s listed before the “fa…” section, possibly because the digraph **æ** comes before **a** in English dictionary order, and is the only entry starting with **fæ**. (I wonder if this lead to it being overlooked when the *PSC* was being assembled.)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I'm pretty sure due diligence was done. The *faerie form* spell's not in the main text nor the index of the *Compendium* in F at all, digraph or no digraph.

Comment: Ah, that’s unfortunate. It’s a shame when errors show up in works that will never get a corrected printing.